# Multiple Meta_Key Select on on Wordpress database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I've developed a query which selects events from Wordpress. I am using the where clause to select where the `meta_value` of the `meta_key` `eventstartdate` is after today.

The issue I'm having now is, I also want filter on a second `meta_value` that being from the `meta_key` '_VenueCity'.

I have tried aliasing the `wp_postmeta` table and doing a where on the `meta_key` but I think I'm missing a join.

This is the code that works without my additional code to get it to work. Can any one advise on how I get this to work?

```
SELECT

`wp_posts`.`ID` AS `EventID`,
`wp_posts`.`post_parent` AS `SeriesID`,
`wp_posts`.`post_title` AS `EventTitle`,
`wp_posts`.`post_content` AS `EventDescription`,
`wp_posts`.`post_excerpt` AS `EventSummary`,
`wp_posts`.`post_name` AS `EventSlug`,
min(`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value`) AS `EventStartDate`,
max(`tribe_event_end_date`.`meta_value`) AS `EventEndDate`,
`wp_posts`.`guid` AS `GUID`

FROM ((`wp_posts` 
JOIN `wp_postmeta` ON
(
  (`wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_postmeta`.`post_id`)
)) 

LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` `tribe_event_end_date` ON
(
  (
    (`wp_posts`.`ID` = `tribe_event_end_date`.`post_id`) AND
    (`tribe_event_end_date`.`meta_key` = '_EventEndDate')
  )
))


WHERE
(
  (`wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = '_EventStartDate') AND
  (`wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'tribe_events') AND
  (`wp_posts`.`post_status` = 'publish') AND
  (`tribe_event_end_date`.`meta_value` >= CURDATE())  
) 

GROUP BY 
`wp_posts`.`ID` 
ORDER BY 
`EventStartDate`,
`wp_posts`.`post_date`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write your query for you but I will give an example of how to get multiple postmeta values. The power will be in the where clause to get the right values.
You should also consider what joins you want to use.

```
SELECT
p.post_title,
pm1.meta_value,
pm2.meta_value

FROM wp_posts as p

INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pm1
ON p.ID = pm1.post_id

INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pm2
ON p.ID = pm2.post_id

WHERE
pm1.meta_key = '_my_postmeta_field1'
AND
pm2.meta_key <> '_not_this_field'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can my existing query be modified to include the new query? I need the existing code to still work.